# Prevent Internet Explorer 8 from asking "Do you wish to close all tabs?"

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, tabbed-browsing

How do I disable the question Do you wish to close all tabs or only the current tab ? I don't find having to click multiple times, of any use. A don't ask me again option would be nice.

Answer (score 9):

This applies to Internet Explorer 7, 8, and 9.

**Uncheck** the following option:

**Internet Options** > **General** > **Tabs** > **Settings** > `[ ] Warn me when closing multiple tabs`

[image: Internet Options]

[image: Tabbed Browsing Settings]

Alternatively, when you get that message box, you can **check**:

`[x] Always close all tabs` (Thank you, [Moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928/moab)).

[image: Close all tabs]